# Ktor - create List from Json file

Tags: kotlin, ktor

i am getting error - This class does not have constructor at `object : TypeToken<List<Todo>>()` + object is not abstract and does not implement object member

```
data class Todo(
    val identifier: Long ,
    val name: String ,
    val description: String
)


class DefaultData {

private lateinit var myService: MyService

@PostConstruct
fun initializeDefault() {
    val fileContent = this::class.java.classLoader.getResource("example.json").readText()

    val todos: List<Todo> = Gson().fromJson(fileContent, object : TypeToken<List<Todo>>() {}.type)

    myService.createTodoFromJsontodos
}
```

}

how can I fix this?

Objective is : To be able to create an endpoint that can get data from json file via service

Is there is a full fledged example

Also how to create interfaces in Ktor? As I want to use Dependency Inversion to enable retrieving data from different sources

Comment: Which version of Gson are you using?

Comment: implementation ("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.7")

Comment: Please share the Ktor related code. You can use Koin https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-ktor/ktor/ to have dependency injection in a Ktor application.

Comment: Hi, its just a starter project. I have a "fun Routing.myRoutes...." and service is not written yet, as I moved code from service to DefaultData . So I dont have much to share, and looking for an example

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin has built-in util similar to `TypeToken`, so I suggest using it instead:

```
Gson().fromJson(fileContent, typeOf<List<Todo>>().javaType)
```

You will need to add a dependency to `kotlin-reflect`. `typeOf()` function is marked as experimental, but I use it for some time already and never had any problems with it.

Also, you said in your comment that this is a starter project. If you don't have any existing code already then I suggest to use `kotlinx-serialization` instead of `Gson`. It is a de facto standard in Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily take advantage of kotlinx-serialization.

Steps:

1. Add the kotlin serialization plugin in your build.gradle file

`kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.5.20"`

```
plugins {
    application
    java
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.5.21"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.5.20"
}
```

2. Add the dependecy for serialization library

```
dependencies {
     ...
     implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.2.2")
}
```

3. Decode your json string to corresponding object using Json decode method

```
val JSON = Json {isLenient = true}
val mytodos = JSON.decodeFromString(message) as List<Todo>
```